# Logical OR (||) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

A book states following rules for OR:

- If the first operand is an object, then the first operand is returned.
- If the first operand evaluates to false, then the second operand is returned.
- If both operands are objects, then the first operand is returned.
- If both operands are null, then null is returned.
- If both operands are NaN, then NaN is returned.
- If both operands are undefined, then undefined is returned.

However I observed following behavior while coding:

```
        var result18 = (NaNVar || undefinedVar);  //undefined
        var result19 = (NaNVar || nullVar);  //null
        var result20 = (undefinedVar || NaNVar);  //NaN
        var result21 = (undefinedVar || nullVar); //null
        var result22 = (nullVar || NaNVar); //NaN
        var result23 = (nullVar || undefined);   //undefined
```

How can I justify this behavior for those rules?

Comment: In any of these cases, the second rule applies: *"If the first operand evaluates to false, then the second operand is returned."*

Comment: Your book seriously has both the first and third bullet points? If so, throw that book out; someone is not thinking rigorously. (The first bullet point already covers the third bullet point.) All you need to know is this: _"If the first operand is 'truthy', evaluate to it; otherwise, evaluate to the second operand."_ One rule. Done. (And then you need to know that non-truthy values are: `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, and `NaN`.)

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz. I was even thinking the same single rule. But cant seriously disrespect the author given his authority on the subject. In fact he is kinda benchmark person for me. For your knowledge the book is Wrox Pro JavaScript by Nicholas C Zakas.

Comment: Am gonna give some more time to dig in what he exactly mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes after observing the results, I concluded two simple rules:

```
        //1: if the first operand evaluates to true then it is returned (here it means actual //value of operand is returned but not the evaluated value that is true)
        //following values evaluates to ture: non-empty string, non-zero number and //none of these values- NaN, null, undefined

        var result = ("Mahesh" || false) //"Mahesh"
        var result = ("Mahesh" || true) //"Mahesh"
        var result = ("Mahesh" || undefined) //"Mahesh"
        var result = ("Mahesh" || null) //"Mahesh"
        var result = ("Mahesh" || NaN) //"Mahesh"
        var result = (5 || false) //5
        var result = (5 || true) //5
        var result = (5 || null) //5
        var result = (5 || NaN) //5
        var result = (5 || undefined) //5

        //2: if first operand evaluates to false then the value of second operand is //returned, again without evaluating it
        //following values evaluate to false: empty string (""), number zero (0),  null, //NaN, undefined or false)

        var result = (false || NaN);  //NaN
        var result = (false || null);  //null
        var result = (false || undefined);  //undefined
        var result = (false || "Mahesh");  //Mahesh
        var result = (false || 5);  //5

        var result = (NaN || false);   //false
        var result = (NaN || true);   //true
        var result = (NaN || NaN);   //NaN
        var result = (NaN || null);  //null
        var result = (NaN || undefined);  //undefined
        var result = (NaN || "Mahesh");   //Mahesh
        var result = (NaN || 5);   //5

        var result = (null || false);  //false
        var result = (null || true);  //true
        var result = (null || NaN); //NaN
        var result = (null || null);  //null
        var result = (null || undefined);   //undefined
        var result = (null || "Mahesh");  //Mahesh
        var result = (null || 5);  //5

        var result = (undefined || false);  //false    
        var result = (undefined || true);  //true
        var result = (undefined || NaN);  //NaN
        var result = (undefined || null); //null
        var result = (undefined || undefined);  //undefined
        var result = (undefined || "Mahesh");  //Mahesh
        var result = (undefined || 5);  //5

        var result = (0 || false); //false
        var result = (0 || true); //true
        var result = (0 || NaN); //NaN
        var result = (0 || null);  //null
        var result = (0 || undefined);   //undefined
        var result = (0 || "Mahesh"); //Mahesh
        var result = (0 || 5); //5

        var result = ("" || false); //false
        var result = ("" || true); //true
        var result = ("" || NaN); //NaN
        var result = (""|| null);  //null
        var result = (""|| undefined);   //undefined
        var result = ("" || "Mahesh"); //Mahesh
        var result = ("" || 5); //5

        //Note: if the first operand evaluates to false and if the second operand is undeclared 
        //variable then it will cause an error
        var result = (false || undeclaredVar);    //error
```

I think that's all in it in simpler words. Can anyone here confirm if I have got right understanding?
I tried this in IE10, hope things will be consistent across other browsers.

Comment: @jncraton can you confirm above understanding

Comment: The third rule isn't needed. Undeclared variables can't be returned, so this causes and error. It's a general rule that applies to the whole language, and not simply to logical or.

Comment: Yeah that's right. But just included as warning note. Ok I updated.

Answer (score 5):

This rule is the key:

> If the first operand evaluates to false, then the second operand is
>   returned.

All of your left hand side values evaluate to false, so the right hand side is returned.

Here's a good definition from MDN if it helps you:

> expr1 || expr2
>
> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either
>   operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: @jmcraton  Yeah I thought that only but did not get how NaN, undefined and null get evaluated to false since when they are second operand in && and the first operand is true, it returns the value of second operand (NaN,null,undefined) not false.
 > var result3 = (trueVar && NaNVar); //NaN    
 > var result4 = (trueVar && nullVar); //null
 > var result5 = (trueVar && undefinedVar); //undefined

Comment: Logical and always returns the right hand side if the left hand side evaluates to false. The right hand side isn't even evaluated in that case. You might want to check out this page on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Yeah that "Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2" was pretty straight forward with hidden meaning. Return "expression" not true or false or more clearly evaluated Boolean value, please see answer I gave at the last. So this "Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false." might be wrong.

Comment: I'm not seeing a case where that would be wrong. If both arguments are boolean values, then a boolean value will always be returned.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the confusion around the description in the book. I was trying to enumerate edge cases and I see how that could cause some confusion.

You can accurately describe the operation using only two rules: if the first argument is truthy then return the first argument; if the first argument is falsy return the second argument. Your third rule doesn't just apply to this operator, an undeclared variable will always causing her to be thrown when you try to use it. It doesn't matter what you try to use it for (with the exception of typeof and delete, which work fine in undeclared variables).

Answer (score 2):

Your book has chosen a terrible way to describe the logical OR operator.

For example, this rule is far too limiting.

> If the first operand is an object, then the first operand is returned.

The operator does not do any sort of type check. It doesn't care if the first or second operand is an "object". It only cares about how they coerce to a boolean.

Take this example.

```
"foobar" || false
```

The first operand is a string, not an object, but it will coerce to the boolean `true`, so the first operand is returned.

```
Boolean("foobar"); // true
```

Your book is walking through bullet points as though it was following some sort of specified algorithm. There is no such algorithm. The comparison is strictly based on Boolean coercion.

To put it simply,

- it evaluates operands from left to right until one is found that will coerce to `true` or until it runs out of operands.
- the last operand evaluated is returned (uncoerced)

> **[11.11 Binary Logical Operators](http://es5.github.com/#x11.11)**
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating LogicalORExpression.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. If `ToBoolean(lval)` is `true`, return `lval`.
> 4. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression.
> 5. Return `GetValue(rref)`.